# Why is a restaurant bill called a "check"?

Tags: etymology

Why is a restaurant bill called a "check" (as in "Check, please!")?

Comment: It's one of the definitions of *[check](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/check)*: 
***25.** a slip or ticket showing the amount owed, especially a bill for food or beverages consumed.*

Comment: @drɱ65δ; why so many downvotes? Questions that ask why and are tagged with etymology are looking for etymology of the word. This is not gen. ref as even http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=check&allowed_in_frame=0 does not explain it fully

Comment: Do you think I have the ability to downvote 4 times on a post? (I just upvoted.)  My comment was merely to point out that there is a separate definition for this usage, and it's not a cheque-sort-of-check.

Comment: @drɱ65δ: Sorry for that, it came out completely and utterly wrong and should have been addressed to down-voters.

Answer (score 9):

This is a good question, and the general references ([Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=check), etc.) are not helpful in getting a definite answer. That is, they give the general etymology of check (it arose from chess, and "All the other senses seem to have developed from this one"), but not of this particular "restaurant bill" sense. Even the Oxford English Dictionary does not explain it; however its classification is suggestive. It says:

> **14.** A means to ensure accuracy, correctness, security from fraud, etc.: as
>     **†a.** The counterfoil of a bank bill, draft, etc.
>       .
>     **b.** A token, usually a memorandum of receipt, a ticket, or piece of metal […] used for the purpose of identification, or as evidence of ownership or title: given, e.g. to the owner of luggage on a railway (as in U.S.), or to one who temporarily leaves luggage, cloaks, […] etc., etc.
>       .
>      **c.** A restaurant bill. Chiefly U.S.
>     *1869* A. D. Whitney …  *I let her settle for the dinner checks.*
>     *1910*   ‘O. Henry’ …  *Through an arched opening‥you thrust your waiter's check and the money.*
>     *1916*  *Variety* … *Inspectors‥ordered drinks and paid their check just before one.*
>     *1937* R. Stout …  *I‥found the waitress and got my check from her.*

(Looking under *cheque*, it seems to have arisen as "a differentiated spelling" of *check* in sense 14a, so the modern meaning of *cheque* (or American *[bank] check*) is different from 14c.)

So to answer your question, we don't know exactly, but the heading under which the OED has put the word suggests that they think it came from "a means to ensure (*check*) correctness". It's not entirely clear what the restaurant bill is meant to check (perhaps the diner checks that he/she is being asked for the correct amount). This listing is still not as definite as an explicit pronouncement on the origin of this sense, so something concrete from a real expert would be useful.

Comment: It seems the mechanisms by which *cheque/check* arrived at its plethora of current meanings are somewhat murky, to say the least. Obviously [rain check](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28838/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-to-take-a-rain-check) is "one of the family", but for some reason Brits have taken that particular one up with US spelling. I think we're in the process of trying to create two distinct words, because the various meanings have diverged so far, but we're not doing a very good job of this so far!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: In fact, if you look at the OED's quotes, those before (say) 1700 seem to use *cheque* and *check* in free variation, in all senses. :-) So I'd say that the well-intentioned British attempt to spin off *cheque* into a different word has not been ideally excecuted.

Comment: Yeah, I think you've just rephrased my thinking better than I did. Bearing in mind *check the bleeding, etc.* at the other end of the semantic spectrum, we Brits really ought to have grasped the nettle and insisted on *rain cheque*. We just bottled it.

Comment: Now that you mention it, a restaurant check and a hat or coat check seem very similar ideas to me: both are a piece of paper identifying the items under consideration. I have always thought it odd that the bill at a restaurant and the payment of that bill can both be called a "check".

Comment: @Jay: Yes, in America you can pay the check with a check, and also pay the bill with bills. :-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: When Americans want to be pretentious, they often use British words or even a fake British accent. I think this is a subtle compliment: We want to sound smart and clever so we talk like you. Or maybe it's an insult: yeah, those Brits are snobby and put on airs. :-)

Answer (score 4):

In the etymonline entry for [check](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=check) you can find:

> c.1700 "a token used to check against loss or theft" (surviving in *hat check*)

Maybe it was first used to call the waiter to bring you your hat (coat, cane, etc.) and the bill; in the "olden" days, when it was customary to wear hats, it was not unusual for restaurants to have hat racks at which people would leave their hats.

Another possibility is that the guest wanted to *check* the bill, before paying for it.

No references to support either theory.

Comment: I think your *guest wanting to check the bill* probably comes closest to answering OP's question. I'd see it as meaning the guest wants a *checklist* of what he's eaten & drunk.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, check the checklist and check things off with a checkmark; supported by international gesture for 'Check, please!' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_gestures

Comment: @Unreason, although Wiki lists a tick as among the symbols, it doesn't give any suggestion as to how common that is compared to the other gestures. I'm only familiar with the scribble, which could be interpreted as a request to write out the bill.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, scribble is my first concrete association, too. However, I think the sign itself is just a symbol for writing. Any writting. The meanings: lets get paper, write, check off, sign cheques, credit card slips, whatever, I am done here, want to go, come take the money, etc..

Answer (score 0):

According to [The Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=check&allowed_in_frame=0), the usage of the word "check" comes from chess, as in "check mate", when the game is over:

> early 14c., "A call in chess noting one's move has placed his
>   opponent's king in immediate peril," from O.Fr. eschequier "a check at
>   chess" (also "chess board, chess set"), from eschec, from V.L.
>   *scaccus, from Arabic shah, from Pers. shah "king," the principal piece in a chess game (see shah; also cf. checkmate). When the king is
>   in check a player's choices are limited. **Meaning widened from chess to
>   general sense of "adverse event" (c.1300), "sudden stoppage"** (early
>   14c.), and by c.1700 to "a token used to check against loss or theft"
>   (surviving in hat check) and "a check against forgery or alteration,"
>   which gave the modern financial use of "bank check, money draft"
>   (first recorded 1798 and often spelled cheque), probably influenced by
>   exchequeur. Meaning "pattern of squares" (c.1400) is short for
>   checker. Checking account is attested from 1923, Amer.Eng.

I assume that either as Unreason said, this could be asking for a "hat check", or more simply, just asking for the end of the meal, since check is the end of a chess game.

It's also extremely possible that it's related to the usage of the word "check" in American English to refer to a form of payment ("cheque" in British English)

Comment: This applies to cheque (bank cheque / bank check), but the meaning in a restaurant bill is a different sense of "check".

Comment: I think it's possible it could be both; i.e. the check is the "sudden stoppage" of the meal / business transaction.

Comment: Unless we find a citation, that is just speculation, right?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR That is correct... this is purely my assumption based on that etymology resource. I would be very interested in a more authoritative answer myself!

Comment: I think both *bank cheque* and *restaurant bill* meanings came via *checkmate/game-over* -> *bring to an end* -> *verify final position* -> *summary of amounts owed*. The bank/restaurant contexts are really the same - except in one they owe you, in the other you owe them. Which does kinda make a difference, but I'm wondering if any Americans really do use spelling to distinguish between them? We Brits always use *cheque* for banks, and our restaurants only ever have *bills* anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Americans use "check" for both bank drafts and restaurant bills. Americans only use "cheque" when they want to sound exotic. I think we usually call the thing at a restaurant a "bill" rather than a "check", though "check" is certainly not unheard of and I doubt anyone would be confused to hear it.

Comment: @Jay: I suppose *cheque* only sounds (looks!?) exotic because it's foreign (ie - British). We Brits now reserve that spelling for *bank* "debt records" - we never ask for a restaurant cheque anyway, so we wouldn't care how it's spelled. But given that we seem to have accepted *rain check* into our vocabulary, I am surprised we haven't made any moves to spell it [rain cheque](http://www.word-detective.com/2009/07/19/rain-check/). But that's a good link for the subject, I think.