# Do we ask for check or cheque in restaurants?

Tags: word-usage, history

I know there is a related question asked [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46251/why-is-a-restaurant-bill-called-a-check). But its slightly different than it and seeking more information.

I live in India, I have been to America couple of times. In my first trip it was surprising to see people asking for "check" instead of "bill". I have been told by my friend that here (in America) they call it "check". I assumed may be it arosed from "check-out".

After some days another friend told me that it's "cheque", **not** "check" and he elaborated that just like how a banker pays money in return of cheque.

After reading few answers/question and links given in the relative [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46251/why-is-a-restaurant-bill-called-a-check), I really made a conclusion that which one is correct to use because I doubt only one has to be correct and remaining evolved by misinterpretation because "check" and "cheque" sound the same?

Comment: AFAIK *cheque* is the British spelling and *check* is the American spelling

Comment: thats why I was wondering why the red lines under "cheque" (spell checker didnt know I was typing UK english lol), and there is no solid historical proof to make a conclusion

Comment: In America, when you go to a bank, you can cash a "check", not a "cheque". Whether it's like that because two words sounded the same or because Americans spell it differently is sort of besides the point. When you ask for the "check" at a restaurant, you're basically playing the role of the banker for the waiters; they bring you a check, and you cash it.

Comment: Can't link to a comment, so copy/paste:  "It's one of the definitions of check: 25. a slip or ticket showing the amount owed, especially a bill for food or beverages consumed. – Daniel δ Oct 25 '11 at 13:36"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cheque is the British spelling for the banking  thing. It is not used in Britain or Australia for restaurants. There you would say "bill" or "account".

Comment: But it is used in Canada,  where cheque is the correct spelling.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between *check* and *checque*. Both are pronounced identically, as /tʃɛk/. The difference between the usage in a restaurant and in a bank is usually distinguished by the articles used.

In a restaurant, (unless you're writing your request to the waiter, which seems unlikely)
you ask for **/ðə'tʃɛk/** (note the definite article *the*).

In a bank, however, you cash **/ə'tʃɛk/** (note indefinite article *a*).

Comment: I know you tried to explain using /tʃɛk/ /ðə'tʃɛk/ /ə'tʃɛk/ but I dont know how to read them :)

Comment: Look up Kenyon and Knott, or International Phonetic Alphabet, or read the instructions in your bilingual dictionary. Or, if you're American, try _[Good Night Moon](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf)._

Answer (score 1):

I’m from Canada, here we request the cheque when we are ready to leave the restaurant. So in my mind it is likely it comes from the uncommon ordeal of signing a cheque to the restaurant.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work. Your answer would benefit from citations of sources (other than yourself).

Answer (score 0):

At restaurants in America, you ask for the "check", not the "bill". Whatever the etymology, that's American usage.

Comment: It's perfectly legit to ask for your "bill" or "tab", though "check" is the more common term.

Comment: And in Canada, we would ask for the cheque after a meal ;)

Answer (score -4):

Its 'Check' not 'Cheque'.... check word also means 'stop or slow the progress of' (something, typically something undesirable). 
for eg: "efforts were made to check the disease" 
Here, we let waiter know that we are done with our food and he can proceed to the next step

Comment: That is not what "check please" means in this case.

Comment: That sounds like your (or somebody's) conjecture about the origin of that meaning, and unless you can produce a reliable source for it, I would discount the suggestion.