# British equivalent of "taking a rain check"

Tags: american-english, british-english, dialectal-equivalent

Is there a British equivalent of "taking a rain check"?

It would be very useful to have a phrase that I can say to British people which means "I need to cancel and I'd like to reschedule but I can't give a specific time right now."

Is there one?

Edit: This phrase is widely recognised in the UK but very rarely used. It is usually misunderstood as meaning "I'd like to reschedule (to a specific time)".

Comment: It's commonplace and pretty well understood in the UK.

Comment: http://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/jargon.htm

Comment: I first heard the expression when I lived in Japan in 1973/4 and had it explained to me by an American colleague. But as @Edwin says it is widely understood in the UK today. Britain is an internationalised country, and not much that happens in the world escapes our notice.

Comment: @WS2 Lynne Murphy of https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/ said in 2011 that it was widely _misunderstood_ in the UK!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80642/im-british-so-should-i-take-a-rain-cheque

Comment: It is not a phrase in common use in the UK, although it is understood. We say in it various ways according to the context, that is, a real reply rather than a euphemism, or an excuse so as not to offend.

Comment: Perhaps you can find an explanation of the idiom that shows it to be chiefly AmE.  My suspicion is that given the ubiquity of the expression in AmE media, it's likely understood by a wide audience including the British.  Or perhaps to rephrase your question as *Is there a more common expression than* . . .

Comment: Well I know what it means but I have never heard it said in real life - only in American TV shows and movies. My location is Ireland. It sounds a little jarring to my ears to be honest.

Comment: @DavidM Apparently it originated with baseball matches - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rain_check . I had vaguely supposed that it meant 'check the weather forecast' until I read explanations online in recent years.

Comment: @user067531 No, that's a different thing. See again.

Answer (score 1):

"*Can I think about that*?..." or "C*an I get back to you [on that]*?" are probably the closest GB to the American 'Raincheck' - which I think is widely understood here.

"*Can I think about / get back to you on that...?*"  is a polite way of avoiding an embarrassing situation, hopefully without hurting anyone's feelings, when: "You must be joking!" is perhaps a little too direct.

Comment: But "take a raincheck" is often used quite literally, meaning "I'd like to do that at a later date".

Comment: @HotLicks You are quite right. I don't think there is an equivalent - at least I can't think of one. The term "raincheck" is not used in the UK - we have similar things, not quite the same, called "pass-outs" - but I've never heard "Can I take a pass-out on that?" (A "pass-out" is a ticket that allows you to leave something for which you have paid an admission, so you can get back in.)

Comment: @WS2 - A "pass-out"?! Never heard of it in SE England. If I wanted to leave somewhere that I wanted to get back into, I'd ask for a "readmission stamp".

Comment: @AndyT Well,  "pass-out" has both a relevant adjectival and noun sense in the OED. Adj *Designating a ticket or other token giving permission for a visitor or patron to leave and later re-enter a theatre, club, etc. 2001 example - ...when the pass-out stamps was luminous.* Noun *A pass-out ticket.1986   Highland News 27 Sept. 52/4   Anyone who has paid to get into the ground will be able to use their admission ticket as a pass-out.*